# How to choose the "best" samples for training KNN classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I want to build a KNN classifier while constraining the number of training samples.
For example, I have the MNIST dataset with a total number of 60K training samples and I'm looking for a way to choose a subset of size `n` of this dataset that will provide the best classifier (in terms of accuracy).
This is equivalent to seeking the `n` samples that best "represent" the data (or data distribution).
Here is some sample code to clarify the issue:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)
n_digits = 10
ims_per_class = list(range(1, 11)) + [12, 15, 20]
scores = []
for i in ims_per_class :
    x_train_k, _, y_train_k, _ = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, train_size=n_digits * i, stratify=y_train, random_state=42)
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
    neigh.fit(x_train_k, y_train_k)
    scores.append(neigh.score(x_test, y_test))
```

The results as expected show that when selecting samples at random, model became better when the number of training samples increases.

[image]

However, if I choose to train the model when each class is represented by a single sample which is the average pixel value, I get much better results:

```
x_train_mean, y_train_mean = zip(*[(x_train[y_train == i].mean(axis=0), i) for i in range(n_digits)])
x_train_mean = np.stack(x_train_mean, axis=0)
neigh.fit(x_train_mean, y_train_mean)
print(neigh.score(x_test, y_test))
0.8203
```

Averaging samples by class is yielding better results than picking samples at random when `n=#classes`, I'm wondering how to extend the selection process when `n>#classes`?

- Currently, the scope of the question is for the case `K=1` (the number of neighbors in the KNN graph), however, solutions that generalize well for different K values are also welcomed!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `n` here. Within the loop, you are using `n` to mean number of images per class. It's already `>#classes` for `n = 11, 12, 15, 20` (assuming 10 classes for MNIST). So what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: `n` is the total number of training samples, if I take a single image per class the best will be to take an average of the class images (i.e. in the case of `n=10` picking an image at random for each class will yield `acc~=0.38` while taking the average value results in `acc=0.82`).  I have edited the code snippet in order to make it clearer.

Comment: I dont understand why would someone want to choose the best N pictures to train their model. If you cherry pick your dataset on your testing their might be a huge error in performance. Am I missing something?

Comment: @itamarkanter to well represent your image distribution just make sure to stratify your data on your y label. Therefore, you will have a train set that is evenly distributed between all the different categories. That is it.

Comment: @ombk I want to choose the best n in order to reduce the size of the KNN model. Note that in the example I provided I train the model with stratified data. But you can see that when taking 10 stratified data points at random (i.e. single image from each class) the results are much worse than taking 10 pseudo-images which are the average pixel intensity of each class. I'm wondering whether I can find a similar approach which will be better than picking image at random (stratifying on y) in case I can choose more than single sample per class

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple approaches suggesting a means how to choose the "best" samples, among them:

- [Condensed nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#CNN_for_data_reduction) (classic, 1968)
- [Stochastic Neighbor Compression](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/kusner14.html) (2014)
- [ProtoNN: Compressed and Accurate kNN for Resource-scarce Devices](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/gupta17a.html) (2017)

But I found that taking a simpler approach, based on clustering, yields decent results.
The idea is very simple, just cluster each class into n "representative" clusters (k-means, but GMM also worked) and use these clusters for training the KNN model.
You can see the gain accomplish by this approach in the following code snippet and graph:

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)

n_digits = 10
ks = list(range(1, 11)) + [12, 15, 20]
scores = []
scores_kmeans = []
for k in ks:
    # naive
    x_train_k, _, y_train_k, _ = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, train_size=n_digits * k, stratify=y_train, random_state=42)
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
    neigh.fit(x_train_k, y_train_k)
    scores.append(neigh.score(x_test, y_test))
    # k-means
    x_train_kmeans = []
    y_train_kmeans = []
    for i in range(n_digits):
        x_train_kmeans.append(KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0, n_init=10).fit(x_train[y_train == i]).cluster_centers_)
        y_train_kmeans.extend([i] * k)
    x_train_kmeans = np.concatenate(x_train_kmeans)
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
    neigh.fit(x_train_kmeans, y_train_kmeans)
    scores_kmeans.append(neigh.score(x_test, y_test))

plt.plot(ks, scores, label='naive')
plt.plot(ks, scores_kmeans, label='k-means')
plt.ylabel('acc')
plt.xlabel('images per class')
plt.legend()
```

[image]